# Check whether a page exists in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I am creating a page in the admin area of Django CMS and I have the `redirect` field under Advanced Settings. How can I check that the URL entered in that field is a valid URL of an existing Django CMS page?

What should I test? I thought about issuing a request to that URL and if it throws a 404, then invalidate the field, but this sounds a bit too far fetched. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `get_page_queryset_from_path` from `cms.utils.page_resolver` and checked that the path entered on the `redirect` field actually returns a valid `Page` using the above function.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your actual page is in a pool of pages

if your page is on the draft mode:

```
from cms.models import Page
your_page.get_path() in [p.get_path() for p in Page.objects.public().published()]
```

with a reverse_id:

```
your_page.get_path() in [p.get_path() for p in Page.objects.all() if p.reverse_id != your_page.reverse_id]
```